# Eclipse graphical layout preview gone

Tags: android, eclipse, layout

I used to be able to see a working preview of what my layout was going to look like in eclipse by clicking on "Graphical Layout" then i could click on another tab called like "main.xml" and see the actual xml code. Now i have 2 tabs called "Design" and "Source".  How can I get my old view back again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:  Right click on the XMLcode layout and then select open With Layout editor. It will show you the Graphical Layout Editor for your Application and then, you'll be able to see the Grapgical view that have coded by XML.

If you don't have Graphical Layout Editor as a choice, you can use Android Common XML Editor.

Answer (score 5):

Right click on XML file, select **`open with -> Android Layout Editor`**.

Answer (score 0):

In the package Explorer Window, go to res / layout and double click the xml file.  When that window pops up you will see a box on the bottom left called "Graphical Layout" where you can switch between the xml editor and Graphical Layout editor.

Answer (score 0):

If you have my problem which is the most annoying one: all the upper line of the graphical layout gone missing. what solve this is to recompile the app with a previous version
pick project than configure and compile with a previous version or the same one probably too small memory and too many tweaks got that out of the eclipse scope.